# Recursive function printing in reverse order

Tags: c, recursion

(I'll start by noting this lab is low level 1st year programing, so high level stuff isn't usable right now for us)

I was given a lab to write a program in C that would accept a number between 1 and 36, six times, then print out those numbers as a bar graph, where the 'bar graph' is a number of # equal to the input number.

e.g. 5 would be:

So far I have this:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

void graphCreate();

int main(void)
{
    graphCreate();
}


void graphCreate()
{
    static int chartLoop = 1;
    int graphLength = 0;
    int graphNumber = chartLoop;

    while(graphLength > 36 || graphLength < 1)
    {
        printf("How long is chart %d?\t", graphNumber);
        scanf("%d", &graphLength); 
    }

    if(chartLoop < 6)
    {
        chartLoop++;
        graphCreate();
    }

    printf("\n%d.\t%d|", graphNumber, graphLength);
    while(graphLength > 0)
    {
        printf("#");
        graphLength--;
    }

}
```

And it does the output as expected... mostly:

```
How long is chart 1?    5
How long is chart 2?    10
How long is chart 3?    15
How long is chart 4?    20
How long is chart 5?    25
How long is chart 6?    30

6.      30|##############################        
5.      25|#########################
4.      20|####################
3.      15|###############
2.      10|##########
1.      5|#####
```

However, I need the final outputs (the bars) in 1 -> 6 order, and it's reversed. What am I doing wrong that it's in reverse?

Comment: Print *before* your recursive call, not after.

Comment: Any output statements in a recursive function which are after the recursive call, will also be output after the call, i.e. on the way back out of the recursion, and so in reverse order.

Comment: If I print before recursion it doesn't get all 6 inputs before giving all 6 outputs, and the requirement is that all 6 have to be put in before it prints out.

Printing before recursion makes it go:

How long is chart 1? 5
#####

How long is chart 2? 10
##########

etc.

Answer (score 0):

If using the recursive way to solve the problem is a requirement, you need to store the outputs and then print them in reverse order.

If recursive is not a requirement, you can loop 6 times to get and store the input numbers and print the bars in sequence.